# Targeting an iFrame inside another page

Tags: php, html, iframe

how do i target an iframe in another page from my current iframe?

For example.

Page1
 -> iFrame (I click a link that would go to the iframe in page2)

Page2
 -> iFrame (view the output made by the link in the iframe in page 1

Comment: there is almost always a better approach than using iframes

Comment: I think it's a little bit too late to change now. or what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The `window` has a `frames` array, you need to access it.

You need to run `window.top.frames[1].src = 'http://...';`.

`window.top` means that you will run this code from the main window.

EDIT:
Assuming that the link is clicked from frame 0 and opened in frame 1.

Comment: so ill just include this in an anchor link?

Comment: To make a link that runs a javascript code, you need to use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol. Something like: `<a href="javascript:window.top.frames[1].src = '';" ..>` or `<a href="javascript:myFunction();" ..>`